# How to pass a file path from .java class file to native jni file

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I want to pass a file path from Java class to native file using jni. In the native implementation file I want to check if file exists or not.

This is my java file:

```
public class FileNative extends Activity {

    String fpath = "storage/emulated/0/Download/view.pdf";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str1 =null;
            Log.d("Click","The button has been clicked to open the file");
            str1 = ndkopenfile(fpath);
        }
    }

    public native String ndkopenfile(String fpath);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("file-jni");
    }
}
```

This is my C++ file:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_filewithnative_FileNative_ndkopenfile(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj , jstring path)
{
    const char* jnamestr = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, 0);
    char retPath[20];
    FILE* fp = fopen(jnamestr,"w+");
    if(fp)
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF(jnamestr);
    }
    else
    {
        return env->NewStringUTF("Error opening file!");
    }
}
```

Please help me figure out why this isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Improved grammar and code layout.

Answer (score -1):

first of all,

> `public native String ndkopenfile(String fpath);
>       static{
>           System.loadLibrary("file-jni");
>       }`

should be within your FileNative class. Second, you'll have to compile your native code as a static library for whatever architectures you want to support (ex: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86) and put them in the appropriate directories within the apk.

You should really read up on the Android NDK and maybe run through a tutorial or two. https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted